# generate pdf with php and attach external pdfs

Tags: php

I want to generate a pdf file with specific user information that I have stored on a mysql database,  and add to it external pdf files that are stored on the server (these external files belong to the same user ). I've tried doing it using TCPDF but it doesn't have the feature of adding external pdf files to the generated file. How can I achieve this?

Comment: yuo can use:$pdf->SetCreator('Your Name');
$pdf->SetAuthor('Your Name');
$pdf->SetTitle('PDF Title');
$pdf->SetSubject('PDF Subject');

Comment: Use a PDF library that supports merging or concatenating PDF files, such as FPDI or TCPDF with an FPDI extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to use library `libmergepdf` you can find it online, with that plugin you can add page PDF to your original PDF, so save tcpdf in a temp folder then add pages from other PDF and save the final output like:

```
require_once('./vendor/autoload.php');

use iio\libmergepdf\Merger;
use iio\libmergepdf\Driver\TcpdiDriver;
$query = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM document"); //query of files
$query->execute();
$result = $query->get_result();
$merger = new Merger(new TcpdiDriver);
$merger->addFile($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/files/temp/' . $nameFile); //original path PDF
while ($document = $result->fetch_array()) {
    $pdf = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $document['urlfile'];
    if (is_file($pdf)) {
        $merger->addFile($pdf);
    }
}
ob_end_clean();
ob_start();
$merger->merge();
```

Comment: how can i save the original tcpdf in a temp folder??

Comment: like that `$tcpdfVariable->Output($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/temp/' . $nameFile, 'F');` (of course you need to have a folder for temp files)

Comment: thanks, but how can i delete the temp file automatically when i'm done with it?

Comment: just use `unlink(path);`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something around these lines:

```php
$pdf = new TCPDF();
$pdf->SetCreator('');
$pdf->AddPage();

// get pdf to be added
$sourceFile = 'path/to/pdfFile.pdf';
$pageCount = $pdf->setSourceFile($sourceFile);
for ($pageNo = 1; $pageNo <= $pageCount; $pageNo++) {
    $templateId = $pdf->importPage($pageNo);
    $pdf->AddPage();
    $pdf->useTemplate($templateId);
}

$pdf->Output($destinationFile, 'F');
```

Comment: useTemplate, setSourceFile and importPage are not defined